# Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

Getting below exception for 2nd call onwards.We are using hibernate 5.6.6.Final

> "message": "Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are facing a bug introduced in Hibernate 5.6.6.Final and fixed in 5.6.9.Final: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15142

Just upgrade your Hibernate version.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if that field is an inner join, in that case you must go to the entity that is relating to your current entity.

**Example:**

```
  @Table(name = "table_item")
    public class DetalleSolicitudArchivo
```

**You need get detail_id:**

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_detail_item_id")
    private Carpeta carpeta;


 @Column(name = "detail_item_id")
private Long detailItemId
```

I hope this you help.